# Refresh automaticatlly the connection with plx on google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a worksheet in google sheets that I'm connecting with plx.

I'd like for an adivse, I want to refresh the date connected with the database everyday at 10am

I know that inside google sheets that we can be able to create triggers and set a specific to work.

About the adise, is it better to only use the function refreshData() with the triggers, or use the entire code that include the Trigger

```
function setTrigger() {

scheduledTrigger(10,00);
}

function scheduledTrigger(hours,minutes){  
ScriptApp.newTrigger("refreshData")
  .timeBased()
  .atHour(hour)
  .nearMinute(minute)  
  .everyDays(1) 
  .create();
}

function refreshData() { 
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data_TAT'), true); 
SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution(); 
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
};
```

Sorry if I'm not clear

Comment: What is the question here? If you have already created the trigger that runs at 10 every day, then you don't have to do anything else since you have already set the trigger to run the refreshData function.

Comment: Hello @Kessy, thanks for your comment. My question is if is better to use the Trigger with inside the code, or create a Trigger and the set the refreshData() only.

Comment: It's better to create only one trigger.  How you do it is your choice.  If your going to do it with script then you should check to see that there is not one already created for a given function.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much @Cooper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is on the comments by @Cooper:

> It's better to create only one trigger. How you do it is your choice. If your going to do it with script then you should check to see that there is not one already created for a given function.